# Castor integration with log4j

Tags: java, spring, log4j, castor

I have integrated Castor within my application for Java - XML mapping and would like to get some logging info via log4j (like inspect the marshalled xml).

I added this to my log4j config file but I'm not seeing any castor related logging.. do i have to do anything additional to get Castor to work with log4j?

Answer (score 0):

Defining a log category will help you

```
log4j.category.org.castor=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if [Serkan Arıkuşu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15407490/453273) is out of date or just incorrect, but in castor-xml 1.4.1, the logging category to use is org.exolab.castor.xml:

```
log4j.category.org.exolab.castor.xml=DEBUG
```